# Double listbox with CollectionType/ChoiceType for user roles

Tags: forms, symfony, roles

With Symfony 4, I don't have this problem : a simple form to choose or edit the role of an user with a listbox.

Since I start a new project with Symfony 5 (with same code) when I edit a user profile, I have a double listbox like this :

[Form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIoNz.png)

One part of the User FormType :

```
$roles = [User::USER_DEFAULT => 'Simple User',
            User::USER_ADMIN_APP => 'App. Admin',
            User::USER_ADMIN_PROJECT => 'Project Admin',
            User::USER_ADMIN => 'Administrator'];

$builder->add('username')
            ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => 'Roles', 'required' => true, 'entry_type' => ChoiceType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false, 'choices' => array_flip($roles)],])
            ->add('password')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
```

In the database, i have a classical json format for user roles

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
private $roles = [];
```

Some data from the fixture, I've created :

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc8ky.png)

I have created a GitHub fresh example in this page : [form-tests-with-CollectionType](https://github.com/Mick3DIY/form-tests-with-CollectionType)

I know, I miss something but what ?? Should I use Data Transformers or Mappers **to have only one listbox choice** ?

Thanks for your lights. ;)

**Update from 2022-05-04 :**

From my old SF4 project to a new SF5 project, the only one change for the Roles field is "Array" to "Json" in Doctrine :

```
//Migration file with "Json"
roles CLOB NOT NULL --(DC2Type:json)

//Migration file with "Array"
roles CLOB NOT NULL --(DC2Type:array)
```

Now, I have a new format in the database for Roles field with "Array" :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:14:"ROLE_ADMIN_APP";}
```

Before with "Json", with my mistake in the fixture "ROLE_USER" :

```
["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN_APP"]
```

And with this change, I have a single listbox with ONLY ONE CHOICE for a user :

```html
<select id="user_roles_0" name="user[roles][0]">
   <option value="ROLE_USER">Simple User</option>
   <option value="ROLE_ADMIN_APP">App. Admin</option>
   <option value="ROLE_ADMIN_PROJECT" selected="selected">Project Admin</option>
   <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Administrator</option>
</select>
```

Finally, I can create or edit a user with a CollectionType and ChoiceType with multiple roles...

Hope it help for future devs/noob like me ;)

Cheers !

Comment: Just have it as a `ChoiceType::class` instead of `CollectionType::class`.. Set `multiple => true` also.

Comment: Thanks, its work but with multiple select choices... I don't want (for the users) to show  multiple roles line. With my first code in SF4, its work fine. I'm lost.. :(

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding what you mean, set `multiple => false` if you don't want them to select multiple roles..

Comment: With multiple => false, I have a Warning message "Array to string conversion", normal. I've rebooted my brain and start from the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
$roles = [
    'Super Admin' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
    'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
    ...
];

$builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'form.label.role',
    'choices' => $roles,
    'required' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => false
]);
```

My `key => value` is reversed and I'm using the ChoiceType directly.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, as I said to Bossman, I don't want to show a multiple choice for the users. Something change in SF5/Form because my first code works well in SF4. To be continued... I'm searching in the docs, any update about this form choice... :)